# How to make page Carousel by fetching images from XML, using actionscript3.0???

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to make a page carousel by fetching images from an XML file. 
I want the layout of pictures, and the pictures should scroll as i click the next button.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Try something yourself and ask for help.  Just asking us to write you some code is most likely not going to happen.  To get the most help its best to attempt some code, and ask specific questions about what you are struggling with.

Comment: I'm not a fan of downvoting questions(I'm not the downvoter btw), but in this case I can see why someone would. Your question more or less reads like this, "do my application for me". You might want to take M.Laing's advice and make an attempt first, then adding said attempt to your question, then asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Here, check this tut out and buy the book :)
http://www.learningactionscript3.com/2008/12/12/grids-image-gallery/